# Combination of Unix/Linux Shell command (to make hardlinks on multiple files)

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, command

In my Unix Administration homework, I have a problem says

"ln" command to make hard links to all the files, in the current directory, beginning with "a", followed by 3 numbers and ending with ".out" into the target directory "x/links/"

I was trying to use

- $ ln | find -name 'a***.out'
- $ ln 'a***.out' x/links

none of these works... Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the loop:
`for x in a[0-9][0-9][0-9].out; do ln $x x/links ; done`

Comment: Thanks for helping! So do I type this directly in the shell? I've never seen people used a loop in the shell as a command.

Comment: well....mine terminal tells me for:Command not found X:Undefined variable. And what does $x mean?

Comment: Are you using bash?? Could x/links be a problem

Comment: just figure out... i do not need the ''(quote)

Comment: $ ln a[0-9][0-9][0-9].out x/links  thanks for helping!